# Insert Google Maps FragmentActivity to another Activity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have implemented a Google Maps fragment and when it begins it goes to the user location zooms etc...

My question is: Is there a way to 'take' this fragment and insert it to another activity? If this cannot be done any other solution is appreciated!

Google Maps code

```
public class Maps extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
   ...
}

private void gotoUserLocation(double lat, double lng, float theZoom){
   ...
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
   ...
}
@Override
protected void onStop(){
   ...
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
  ...
}
```

}

As i said this prints to the user in full screen the Map with zoom in the user location. Can i take this map and insert it to another activity?

Thanks!

Comment: So you want to take all the zooming and animation code and make it available in another activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to make your zooming and animation code available in another activity,  why not move the zooming and animation code into a separate class that has static methods which do your animation?

For example, in your `onMapReady( )`, you could do this:

`MapAnimationUtils.moveToUserLocation(map, lat, lng, zoom);`

Comment: So what you suggesting is to simplify my code in Maps by implementing some functions in another class and use the same functions in the other activity? Sounds like a good idea

Comment: Absolutely.  All what needs to be shared should be moved to another class.

Comment: Thanks Big Boy :D. I'll do it that way